# Term for a slice of a multi-dimensional array or tensor

Tags: matrix, terminology

*Ported from English Language & Usage -> Mathematics*

And then:

*Ported from Mathematics -> SO*

I'm in the market for a mathematical (or otherwise) **term to describe a slice of a hypercube**.

*Tensor* is out of the running as that's the name of the object I am slicing.

The second I could use a hand with is a term to describe an index (or *access point*) that spans more than a single point in each dimension.

Though about using *Ranged Index* as a collection of *Ranged Dimension*, but I'm **really** hoping there's a more concise and explicit alternative.

For example:

- **Regular index** `[1, 2, 1]` would access index 1 in dimension-one, index 2 in dimension-2 and index 1 in dimension-3
- **Spanning Index (or whatever)** `[3->4, 1, 4->9]` would access all elements between indices 3 and 4 of dimension-1, index 1 of dimension-2, etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first is a [hyperplane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperplane).

The second would be a rectangle in 3 dimensions, so a [hyperrectangle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperrectangle) in more than three. (Or possibly, *n-orthotope* as in the wiki article, depending on how geeky you want to be.)